# Algolia links posts to a 0.0.7.227 url

Tags: gatsby, algolia, netlify

I have two identical sites. One is for testing purposes and the other is for production.

Both sites are successfully deployed via netlify and algolia is successfully indexed. All search bar functions work fine. However for the production site, when the actually posts themselves are clicked, algolia changes the root to a strange 0.0.7.227 url. This does not happen for the testing site. Both sites are identical in code except the algolia env variables.

The production [site](https://yonseiuicscribe-master.netlify.app/search/) and its [github](https://github.com/uicscribe/yonseiuicscribe)

The testing [site](https://yonseiuicscribe.netlify.app/search) with no problems and its [github](https://github.com/develijahlee/yonseiuicscribe)

Why does this problem appear on one but not the other when they are both essentially the same?

I am generating my search results URL from `src/pages/search.js`

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import PageBreadcrumb from "../components/pageBreadcrumbs"
import SEO from "../components/seo"
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite';
import { InstantSearch, SearchBox, Hits } from 'react-instantsearch-dom';

const searchClient = algoliasearch('L939SA528T', '6bf2bcd990937092c431629e2b44740d');
const Hit = ({ hit }) =>
<article>
    <Link to={`/${hit.fields.slug}`}>
        <h1>{hit.title}</h1>
        <h2>{hit.date}{" "}by{" "}<span>{hit.author}</span>{" "}</h2>
        <p>{hit.excerpt}</p>
    </Link>
</article> 

export default class extends React.Component {
    
    render() {
        return (
            <Layout>
                <PageBreadcrumb crumbs={ [ 'Home', 'Search' ] } />
                <div className="searchbarContainer">
                <SEO title="Search - Yonsei UIC Scribe | Underwood International College"></SEO>
                    <InstantSearch className="searchbar" searchClient={searchClient} indexName="Articles">
                        <SearchBox />
                        <Hits hitComponent={Hit} />
                    </InstantSearch>
                </div>
            </Layout>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you generating the URLs for the links?

Comment: updated the question to show that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `/` from `<Link to={`/${hit.fields.slug}`}>` solved the problem